# syntaxt error on rake asset precompile for production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push my app to heroku,

When I am doing `$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`

I am getting

> rake aborted!
>   Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...overflow:hidden": expected "{", was ";width:100%;hei..."
>   (sass):6888

Not able to figure out the exact issue here. Can someone help me out.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your sass file.

Comment: that's what I am not able to find, anywhere in any of the css files

Comment: if you start your server locally and visit a page, the error should be more descriptive -- should tell you what file the syntax error is on.

Comment: I am not getting anything anywhere locally

Comment: Let us see the full error stack.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the semicolon after `overflow:hidden`, it would help if you pasted your actual SASS/SCSS file!

Comment: I don't think so -- look at the second line of the rake error: `";width:100%;hei..."` The first symbol is a semicolon.

Comment: I am not missing any semicolon anywhere.

Comment: @Suraj are you able to provide the css file?

Comment: @Suraj whats happens if you use this instead? [scss code](http://pastebin.com/qp6cLZFT) I converted your CSS code to SCSS.

Comment: I'll have to rename the file to `scss`??

Comment: Usually it would be application.css.scss!